# In my C# project I get "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory..." when specific code executed

Tags: c#, exception, memory, dll

I have a C# project with .NET6 Framework. When a specific code path is executed I get always exception "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."HResult= -2147467261. Source "AGL4DotNET.4" (3.party dll that I am using). The exception comes excactly then when I try to pass a pointer type output from one function to another function.

I have read that many things can be the cause related this exception. My question is:

As the source of the exception is a dll file, does it mean that the code in the dll is causing this problem? Or is it possible that I have made a programming failure related the usage of the dll? Because the problem is memory related, is it possible that I have a memory or cache problem? How can I localize the problem?

My code that is bringing this problem is below: When the method is executed the first time then everything is OK, but when its executed the second or third time (when the function AGL4.Read_var_list_names is no more executed) then I get the exception on the last line. We have contacted the dll's vendor. They just suggested us to pass the root_info not by value but by reference, because root_info shall be a pointer. But I don't got this point excactly.

```
   public AGL4.Datafield root_info_2 = new AGL4.Datafield();
   public void Read_variables(int p_conn_nr)
    {            
        if (run_once == false)
        {
            AGL4.Datafield root_info = new AGL4.Datafield();                
            res = AGL4.Read_var_list_names(p_conn_nr, ref root_info);
            root_info_2 = root_info;
            run_once = true;              
        }    

        AGL4.Read_var_list_values(root_info_2); //here i get the exception
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in their code. Without seeing what they are doing exactly it's hard to say